# 3D arrays in Scheme language

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, scheme, lisp

- I know how to work with 2D and 3D arrays in different imperative languages like c, c++ etc. but
- I am a newbie to functional programming languages. and I am working
  now in Scheme Language which is a dialect of Lisp. I was intending to
  use 3D arrays in the Scheme language to understand how 3D arrays work in Functional Programming languages, specially Scheme. I have searched
  but didn't find any useful resource to work.like
  https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-25.html
- An **example** of 3D arrays in Scheme would be appreciated.

Comment: You are probably looking for purely functional data structures ([paper as PDF](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) and [scheme implementation](https://github.com/ijp/pfds)), however looking for resources for a general topic is off topic here on SO.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using racket vectors:

```
#lang racket

;; Dimension sizes
(define x-size 10)
(define y-size 10)
(define z-size 10)

;; Create a 3D vector with a default value of 1
(define my-3D-vector
  (make-vector x-size (make-vector y-size (make-vector z-size 1))))

;; Returns the element in slot (x-pos, y-pos, z-pos) of 3D-vec.
;; The first slot is (0,0,0) and the last slot is
;; (x-size - 1, y-size - 1, z-size - 1)
(define (3D-vector-ref 3D-vec x-pos y-pos z-pos)
  (vector-ref (vector-ref (vector-ref 3D-vec x-pos) y-pos) z-pos))

;; Updates the slot (x-pos, y-pos, z-pos) of 3D-vec to contain v
(define (3D-vector-set! 3D-vec x-pos y-pos z-pos v)
  (vector-set! (vector-ref (vector-ref 3D-vec x-pos) y-pos) z-pos v))
```